# How to stop creating files at a specific number?

Tags: linux, bash, centos

I want to create 900 files with 3 letter names.

Example: `xyz.txt`, where `x`, `y`, and `z` are different letters from `a` to `z`.

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
for ((i=1; i < 900; i++))
      do touch {a..z}{a..z}{a..z}$i.txt
done
```

I expect it to stop at 900.

But in the end I'm creating over 10K of files. Can someone please help me accomplish this?

Comment: What do you expect this syntax (`{a..z}{a..z}{a..z}$i.txt`) to do?

Comment: I expect it to create XXX.txt files and stop at 900.

Comment: 26 * 26 * 26 is 17,576; which 5% of those do you actually want to create?

Comment: @chepner I want the name to be with different letters. Good example: ABC.txt, AZY.txt and etc.   Bad example: AAB.txt, YYZ.txt and etc. Doesn't matter which letters, they just need to be different.

Comment: The "must be different" requirement is not mentioned in the question at all. What about `aba.txt`? Not good either?

Comment: Yes, you're right. I should have been more precise regarding "different". Aba.txt is not ok, because it has the letter "a" twice. Abz.txt is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid any names with repeating characters before the period, as alluded to in comments, you could do this:

```
printf '%s.txt\n' {a..z}{a..z}{a..z} | grep -vE '(.).?\1.?\.' \
    | head -n 900 | xargs touch
```

- The `printf` statement prints the list from `aaa.txt`, `aab.txt` to `zzz.txt`.
- `grep -vE '(.).?\1.?\.'` filters any names where the three characters before the period are not unique: `aaa.txt`, `aab.txt`, `aba.txt` and `baa.txt` are all filtered.
- `head -n 900` gets the first 900 names from the list
- `xargs touch` calls `touch` as few times as possible but will make sure the command line never is too long.

If you want to randomize the file names (but still adhere to these criteria), you can shuffle them before selecting 900:

```
printf '%s.txt\n' {a..z}{a..z}{a..z} | grep -vE '(.).?\1.?\.' \
    | shuf | head -n 900 | xargs touch
```

Comment: `printf '%s\n' {a..i}{j..q}{r..z} {r..z}{j..q}{a..d}` gives me 936 strings which all obviously fulfill the requirement.

Comment: @tripleee You should put that as an answer, it's very elegant.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with 2 lines:

```
all=( {a..z}{a..z}{a..z}.txt )
touch "${all[@]:0:900}"
```

(assuming your OS allows a commandline with 900 arguments). If y ouwant something other than the first 900 such files, you'll need to do something more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

The filenames remind the [`split`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/split.1.html) default output naming. So you could split an empty file to 900 files.

```
split /dev/null -n900 -a3 --additional-suffix=".txt" ""
```

Answer (score 0):

The following generates 910 names, and discards the last 10 before passing them to `touch`.

```
printf '%s.txt\n' {a..m}{p..v}{0..9} | head -n 900 | xargs touch
```

You might be able to find a combination which generates exactly 900 alternatives so you can just `touch <pattern>` and have the shell expand it to the required number of unique names.

Comment: All numbers without any digit appearing twice in the name would produce 738 unique names, but that includes some single- and double-digit numbers. If you require three digits, there are 648 combinations.